# Careers 2.0 - Employer View and Privacy Settings

Tags: support, jobs

In my Careers 2.0 job seeker profile there are two options: Employer View and Privacy Settings. These are my questions:

- When the Employer View is "searcheable", does it mean that an
  employer can see my profile, after he/she performs a search (even if my privacy setting is set to "private")?
- Is it necessary to turn the privacy settings to "public", in order for the job seekers to see my profile? Is this option only purpose to expose my profile to the exterior of the careers site?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Public": This means that a link to the provided path is viewable by anyone. For example my public profile is up at http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jasonpunyon. This setting has no bearing on whether you show up in employer searches.

"Searchable": This means that you will show up in Employer Searches. "Blocked" means you won't show up in any searches. This has no bearing on whether your public profile is visible at your chosen public URL (like http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jasonpunyon).